# Gradle: Execution failed for task ':*application-name-here*:compileDebugNdk', where can I see the adequate error messages?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting this when I am trying to compile and launch:

```
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':*application-name-here*:compileDebugNdk'. > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/path/to/android-ndk/ndk-build'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

OK cool, it is about compilation error, but where can I see compiler error messages?

I set ndk up with:

```
defaultConfig {
    ...

    ndk {
        moduleName "blahblah"
    }
}
```

(I've made my code broken intentionally (it is in hello world state now), the question is about how to get error messages if code is broken during development, not about fixing those errors)

IntelliJ IDEA 14.1, Gradle 2.2.1, Android-NDK r10d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the error messages thrown back by ndk-build through Android Studio "Messages" and the Gradle Console:

[image: AS Screenshot - Messages and Gradle console]

Comment: thank you! 

however, i did not find the gradle console on it's own in the IntelliJ, so i solved this by selecting task named compileDebugNdk and executing it separately - console appears for the task results, no extra stuff